# Deleting dynamically options from select box that were selected in other select box,

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, drop-down-menu

I have two `select box` in `Jquery Mobile`  with the same data - options. at the beginning when I initialize the page I build them dynamically:

```
    var first = document.getElementById("selectBoxFirst");
    var second = document.getElementById("selectBoxSecond");

    for (var i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) 
    {
        first.options[i] = new Option(this.data[i].option, this.data[i].optionId);
        second.options[i] = new Option(this.data[i].option, this.data[i].optionID);
    }
```

I try to do the next thing: When user select an option in one select-box , this option will be deleted in the second one... 
if you choose an different option again so this last option will be deleted from the second and the previos will be shown,and so on...

any ideas how to implement it?

Comment: is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/bH2we/ in this demo, you can remove one option at a time.

Comment: @Omar thanks for the example but choosing one option do not delete this option in the second check box. I look for something similar to that : [ jsfiddle.net/igtr/vHxhx ] - the only problem with that is after choosing item in checkBox1 you get in the second n-1 option, and select again in checkBox2 will lead to n-2 in the first checkbox

Comment: sorry, there is a mistake in my demo. So you want to choose one option at once, no more than once option can be chosen at the same time?

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/TRTrd/

Comment: @Omar after selecting different options on select box's, I end up with only 2 options in one selected box and 4 in the second one. Earlier you suggested using .hide() <option>, I think it's a good solution, not?

Comment: hide/show works, but i dont know whether its compatible with all browsers. the latest demo is a bit complex and requires a lot of logic and comparisons, in order not to add the same value several times. it should always end up with 5 options in one selectmenu and 4 in the other one.

Comment: "always end up with 5 options" - are you able to get an status of 4 options in one and 2 options in second?"?  About the hide/show..I think it's valid html5.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39362/discussion-between-omar-and-dima)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose either to hide or disable selected option.

1. **Hide selected option**: *(This might not work for old browsers)*

   - CSS:

     ```
     .hide { 
       display: none;
     }
     ```
   - JS

     ```
     $('#first').on('change', function () {
       $('select option.hide').removeClass('hide');
       var sel = $('option:selected', this).index();
       $('#second option:eq("' + sel + '")').addClass('hide');
     });

     $('#second').on('change', function () {
       $('select option.hide').removeClass('hide');
       var sel = $('option:selected', this).index();
       $('#first option:eq("' + sel + '")').addClass('hide');
     });
     ```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/tr65t/)**

---

1. **Disable selected option:** *(This doesn't work for IE7 and earlier versions)*

   - JS

     ```
     $('#first').on('change', function () {
       $('select option:disabled').prop('disabled', false);
       var sel = $('option:selected', this).index();
       $('#second option:eq("' + sel + '")').prop('disabled', true);
     });

     $('#second').on('change', function () {
       $('select option:disabled').prop('disabled', false);
       var sel = $('option:selected', this).index();
       $('#first option:eq("' + sel + '")').prop('disabled', true);
     });
     ```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/qMxy3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Using plain JavaScript the approach is rather straightforward:

```
var select1 = document.getElementById('first'),
    select2 = document.getElementById('second');

select1.addEventListener('change', function() {
    while (select2.firstChild) {
        select2.removeChild(select2.firstChild);
    }
    for (var i = 0, len = this.options.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (this.options[i].value !== this.value) {
            select2.appendChild(this.options[i].cloneNode());
        }
    }
}, false);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Tp2z7/

---

You can write the same with jQuery a bit shorter:

```
$('#first').on('change', function() {
    $('option:not(:selected)', this).clone().appendTo($('#second').empty());
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Tp2z7/1/

Comment: Tried the  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tp2z7/)  example - its not working.
after selecting option in the first select box the second is empty.
selecting in the second not change the options in first select box.

Comment: @Dima What browser do you use? The first approach should work fine in all modern browsers. Try the jQuery approach, maybe it will be better for you.

Comment: @VisionN the jQuery example works! I use Chrome(11 version). Unfortunately my project works with jQuery 1.6.4 and the `.on` event don't exist there. How can I replace it?

Comment: @Dima With simple `.change()` or `.bind('change', ...)`.

Comment: you mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Tp2z7/3/ its better to hide/show instead of deleting. @Dima

Comment: @Omar Hiding `<option>` elements is not browser consistent.

Comment: @VisioN There's a bug there. If I add the same thing for the second check box : `$('#second').on('change', function() {
    $('option:not(:selected)', this).clone().appendTo($('#first').empty());
}); ` so after playing with those check box's each iteration delete one item in the second one

Comment: @Dima This is not a bug. Your code will not work in the case you've described in the question. It does the job only in case if you change the first DDL.

Comment: Why? look at that example : http://jsfiddle.net/igtr/vHxhx you have 5 items.
when you choose one option in #first you get 4 options in #second.
now when you choose item in #second you getting in #first only 3 items,and so on...

Comment: @VisioN, why hiding `<option>` elements is not browser consistent? it works on all browsers